# Ballerina: How to connect Oracle database with Ballerina?

Tags: database, ballerina

I am new to Ballerina. How to create a connection to an Oracle database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ballerina, to connect to a database, we have to create a client (or rather an endpoint) of type **jdbc**. For example, if we want to connect to a mysql database you can create a jdbc client as below

```
endpoint jdbc:Client testDB {
   url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb",
   username: "root",
   password: "root",
   poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 }
};
```

In the above example, the url field specify the database connection url. So if the database is **oracle**, then we can use the oracle based url scheme instead as below.

```
endpoint jdbc:Client testDB {
   url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/testdb",
   username: "test",
   password: "test",
   poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 }
};
```

Once you have created a client, then you can use it to do your operations based on the requirement. For example, the below code segment will create a new table in the database connected from the client.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/jdbc;

endpoint jdbc:Client testDB {
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/testdb",
    username: "test",
    password: "test",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 }
};

function main(string... args) {
    var result = testDB->update("CREATE TABLE customers (customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
                                customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL, city varchar2(50))");

    match result {
        int retInt => io:println("status: " + retInt);
        error e => io:println("failed: " + e.message);
    }
}
```

You also have to drop the Oracle JDBC driver jar into BALLERINA_HOME/bre/lib to get this working.

For a complete set of operations, you can refer this guide - https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/jdbc-client.html